# Get file object from path in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

I'm working on a browser extension, wherein part of the feature is that a user can open an image from the browser -> right-click on the image, a context menu is shown -> User clicks on a menu item which says "Upload" (put there by my extension). Clicking that triggers my javascript code which gets the file path, because it will be the `src` property of the image loaded in the browser. Now that I have the file path, I want to upload this file to a server of the app. (Obviously , this is a user-approved request because the user himself selected "Upload" from the menu, so no security breach.)

My idea was to create a `File` object `selectedFile` with the obtained path then use something like `xhr.send(selectedFile)` to upload the file. That is how it's done with the  HTML 5 File API. I however don't know how to create the file object from the path. Is that possible? Note that there is no `<input>` element here, it's part of an extension.

Thanks.

Comment: Just make the server get the file using the image path. Why bothering the client (and you even cannot)?

Comment: How can server fetch from the client like that?

Comment: The client sends the image path to the server, and the server gets the image.

Comment: The file path would be a local path. Like C:\Pictures\abc.png, something like that. How can the server fetch the file with that? It's not possible that way.

Comment: So it's a local file? Indeed, it's not possible. Just like it's not possible to create a `File` object and autonomously upload it to a server, because that would *definitely* be a security breach. The user *must* provide the file with a *deliberate* action through any known method - like using `<input type=file>` elements or performing drag & drop actions, not some fancy extension. At this point you must provide some additiona informations: why are we dealing with a *local* image? What's the page like?